# ArchLinux: Still having the wrong editor in some cases

Tags: shell, arch-linux, editors, latex

After the installation of my ArchLinux OS, the default text editor was set to `vi`. I wanted to change it to `vim` and edited all possible configurations, such as `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.zshenv` and `/etc/environment`. I also tried to use the `export`-command to set the environment variables.
It works now in most cases, but I've experienced one case where the computer still prefers `vi`. If I process a .tex-file with the console and the `tex`-command and type E when experiencing an error (should open the file in the editor), it still wants to open `vi`. I don't think this is a problem of the configuration of tex, but I don't have any more ideas which config I may have overseen.

Comment: What does the output of `echo ${EDITOR}` produce?

Comment: Further to that, you should be specific in the question about what environment variables you set.  It is unfortunately not as well known as it should be that there are at least _two_ environment variables of interest.

Comment: @eyoung100: The output (as expected) is `vim`.

Comment: @JdeBP: I always set both `EDITOR` and `VISUAL`, is that what you want to know?

Comment: If EDITOR is set correctly, the issue is with the application.

Comment: @eyoung100: Still wondering why vi is set by default (it was not installed at the moment of the installation of tex.

Comment: Because it's Tex's issue.  Check the Tex man page

Comment: `sudo rm /usr/bin/vi;sudo ln -s /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vi`

Comment: @cylgalad I would suggest to actually uninstall `vi` instead of just removing the binary. Otherwise a package update might either fail or just replace the link with a binary again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The `e` response to TeX's error prompt causes the system default editor to start up at the current line of the current file.  The environment variable `TEXEDIT` can be used to change the editor used.](https://manned.org/tex.1#head3)

Debian changes the default to `sensible-editor`, which looks up `VISUAL` and `EDITOR`. But by default `TEXEDIT` is vi.

Comment: Thank you, I already found this information in the TeX Q&A. Can you tell me in what config file I have to set the `TEXEDIT` variable to make this setting permanent?

Comment: @ixolius `export TEXEDIT="$EDITOR"` in `~/.profile`, just after `export EDITOR=vim`.